# Using inotify why is my watched file ignored?

Tags: d, inotify

I'm writing a file watcher in [D](http://dlang.org/) on Linux using the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) subsystem for event notification. I've written some code below and i'm nearly there but i have a problem that the watched file is switched to ignored and no more events are raised for it.

It looks like this guy is having a similar problem but there are no answers there: [Inotify vim modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409843/inotify-vim-modification)

Consider the following code:

```
/**
 * Imports.
 */
import core.sys.posix.unistd;
import core.sys.posix.sys.select;
import inotify;
import std.stdio;

/**
 * Main.
 */
void main(string[] arguments)
{
    immutable int EVENT_BUF_LEN = (1024 * (inotify_event.sizeof + 16));

    auto inotifyInstance = inotify_init();

    if (inotifyInstance >= 0)
    {
        string watchedFile = "/home/gary/Desktop/test.txt";
        char[EVENT_BUF_LEN] buffer;
        void* pointer;

        auto watchDescriptor = inotify_add_watch(inotifyInstance, cast(char*)watchedFile, IN_ALL_EVENTS);

        while (true)
        {
            fd_set rfds;
            FD_ZERO(&rfds);
            FD_SET(inotifyInstance, &rfds);

            timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec  = 5;
            timeout.tv_usec = 0;

            if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, null, null, &timeout))
            {
                auto inotifyResult = read(inotifyInstance, buffer.ptr, buffer.length);

                for (pointer = buffer.ptr; pointer < buffer.ptr + inotifyResult; )
                {
                    inotify_event* event = cast(inotify_event*)pointer;

                    if (event.mask & IN_ACCESS)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_ACCESS");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_MODIFY)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_MODIFY");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_ATTRIB)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_ATTRIB");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_CLOSE_WRITE");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_OPEN)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_OPEN");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_MOVED_FROM");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_MOVED_TO)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_MOVED_TO");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_CREATE)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_CREATE");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_DELETE)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_DELETE");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_DELETE_SELF)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_DELETE_SELF");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_MOVE_SELF)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_MOVE_SELF");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_UMOUNT)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_UMOUNT");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_Q_OVERFLOW)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_Q_OVERFLOW");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_IGNORED)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_IGNORED");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_CLOSE)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_CLOSE");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_MOVE)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_MOVE");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_ONLYDIR)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_ONLYDIR");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_DONT_FOLLOW)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_DONT_FOLLOW");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_EXCL_UNLINK)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_EXCL_UNLINK");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_MASK_ADD)
                    {
                        writeln("IN_MASK_ADD");
                    }

                    writefln("wd: %s - mask: 0x%08x - cookie: %s - len: %s", event.wd, event.mask, event.cookie, event.len);

                    pointer += inotify_event.sizeof + event.len;
                }

            }
        }

        inotify_rm_watch(inotifyInstance, watchDescriptor);
        close(inotifyInstance);
    }
}
```

If i perform the following actions, i get the following results:

1. touch ~/Desktop/test.txt

   > IN_OPEN
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00000020 - cookie: 0 - len: 0
   >   IN_IGNORED
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00008000 - cookie: 0 - len: 0
2. echo "Mary had a little lamb." >> ~/Desktop/test.txt

   > IN_OPEN
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00000020 - cookie: 0 - len: 0
   >   IN_IGNORED
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00008000 - cookie: 0 - len: 0
3. Open in Vim, modify and :wq

   > IN_OPEN
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00000020 - cookie: 0 - len: 0
   >   IN_IGNORED
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00008000 - cookie: 0 - len: 0

Nothing seems to work here and the file is ignored after the open event is triggered.

If i alter the code and change the `IN_ALL_EVENTS` flag (which checks for all events) and use `IN_MODIFY` instead, i get the following:

1. touch ~/Desktop/test.txt

   > No result.
2. echo "Mary had a little lamb." >> ~/Desktop/test.txt

   > IN_MODIFY
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00000002 - cookie: 0 - len: 0
3. Open in Vim, modify and :wq

   > IN_IGNORED
   >   wd: 1 - mask: 0x00008000 - cookie: 0 - len: 0

Only point 2 seems to work correctly.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here and any thoughts about changing the code to correctly get all the modification events for a file?

Answer (score 8):

After some reading i've modified the code a little and seems to have solved the problems. Appending to the file raises a `IN_MODIFY` event which is caught nicely. Touch raises a `IN_ATTRIB` which we can treat as a modification. Vim (and other editors) raise `IN_ATTRIB`, `IN_DELETE_SELF` and `IN_MOVE_SELF` events before raising a final `IN_IGNORED` so i can handle these now i know. If i encounter a `IN_IGNORED` event, i re-initialize inotify.

```
/**
 * Imports.
 */
import core.sys.posix.unistd;
import core.sys.posix.sys.select;
import inotify;
import std.stdio;

/**
 * Main.
 */
void main(string[] arguments)
{
    immutable int  EVENT_BUFFER_LENGTH = (inotify_event.sizeof + 16) * 1024;
    immutable uint NOTIFICATION_FLAGS  = IN_MODIFY | IN_ATTRIB | IN_DELETE_SELF | IN_MOVE_SELF | IN_IGNORED;

    auto inotifyInstance = inotify_init();

    if (inotifyInstance >= 0)
    {
        string watchedFile = "/home/gary/Desktop/test.txt";
        char[EVENT_BUFFER_LENGTH] eventBuffer;
        void* eventPointer;

        auto watchDescriptor = inotify_add_watch(inotifyInstance, cast(char*)watchedFile, NOTIFICATION_FLAGS);

        while (true)
        {
            fd_set fileDescriptorSet;

            FD_ZERO(&fileDescriptorSet);
            FD_SET(inotifyInstance, &fileDescriptorSet);

            timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec  = 5;
            timeout.tv_usec = 0;

            if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &fileDescriptorSet, null, null, &timeout))
            {
                auto bytesRead = read(inotifyInstance, eventBuffer.ptr, eventBuffer.length);

                for (eventPointer = eventBuffer.ptr; eventPointer < eventBuffer.ptr + bytesRead; null)
                {
                    inotify_event* event = cast(inotify_event*)eventPointer;

                    if (event.mask & IN_MODIFY || event.mask & IN_ATTRIB)
                    {
                        writeln("Modified");
                    }

                    if (event.mask & IN_DELETE_SELF || event.mask & IN_MOVE_SELF || event.mask & IN_IGNORED)
                    {
                        writeln("Modified");
                        inotify_rm_watch(inotifyInstance, watchDescriptor);
                        close(inotifyInstance);
                        inotifyInstance = inotify_init();
                        watchDescriptor = inotify_add_watch(inotifyInstance, cast(char*)watchedFile, NOTIFICATION_FLAGS);
                    }

                    eventPointer += inotify_event.sizeof + event.len;
                }
            }
        }

        inotify_rm_watch(inotifyInstance, watchDescriptor);
        close(inotifyInstance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! You don't need to remove the watch, close the inotify instance by file descriptor and initialize inotify all over again at every file modification. It works without the 4 lines after writeln("Modified").

Comment: According to docs, IN_IGNORED is issued when either the watch or the file itself is explicitly removed (also when file system is unmounted). I think it is better to watch a folder and match the name in the inotify_event.

Comment: @Trevor Donahue Do you mean to say just do this: close(inotifyInstance); and inotifyInstance = inotify_init();? I guess we need to do this only for these events right: IN_DELETE_SELF, IN_MOVE_SELF, IN_IGNORED. We dont need to do this for every modify. Isnt it ?